# How to filter and read the multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

it's my first question here. I hope I will not be annoying.

I have to read array and put the data to JS script.

**This is var_dumped data from array:**

```
array(2406) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(4) "Mazda"
    ["model"]=>
    string(9) "CX-4"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(4) "Mazda"
    ["model"]=>
    string(19) "CX-5"
    }

    [...]

    [120]=>  
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(12) "Mercedes"
    ["model"]=>
    string(10) "E-class"
    }
    [121]=>  
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(12) "Mercedes"
    ["model"]=>
    string(10) "S-class"
    }
    [122]=>
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(9) "Volkswagen"
    ["model"]=>
    string(10) "Golf"
    }
    [123]=>
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(9) "Volkswagen"
    ["model"]=>
    string(10) "Polo"
    }
    [124]=>
    array(2) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(9) "Volkswagen"
    ["model"]=>
    string(10) "Touareg"
    }
}
```

**And I have to return script like this:**

```
"Mazda" : { // the brand
        "CX-4",// the list of brand’s models
        "CX-5",
    },
    "Mercedes" : {
        "E-class",
        "S-class",
    },    
    "Volkswagen" : {
        "Golf",
        "Polo",
        "Touareg",
    },
```

I really need this and I don't have any ideas to solve it. Please help me.

I've tried to use:

```
foreach($row as $brand => $key){
            echo "\"$brand\" : {\n";
                print $key[model];  

            echo "},\n";
            }
```

But unfortunately it returns only

```
"Mazda" : {
CX-4},
"Mercedes" : {
E-class},
"Volskwagen" : {
Golf},
```

Only one model for one brand :-/

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately SO **is not a free coding service**. You have to have attempted something. If you have a specific issue with what **you** have coded, we are more than happy to help.

Comment: I've tried so much ways to print this data, i.e. foreach in foreach, foreach for array, but every try ends with no results :(

Comment: @gklinek Then show your work and your code. Edit your question and add your best or your last attempt.

Comment: And you dont have long. One more close vote and this question is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this :

```
foreach($row as $brand => $innerArray){
    echo "\"$brand\" : {\n";
    foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
       echo $value . "<br/>";
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's the same :( 

Is there posibility to filter arrays before? For example to find every model of the brand?